# Can't install PuLP in Anaconda, unsatisfiableError

Tags: python, anaconda, pulp

Hi im trying to install PulP in Anaconda and obviously i googled it so I know that you should just write:

```
conda install -c primer pulp
```

writing this in the Anaconda i get:

```
Fetching package metadata.......
Solving packackage specifications: .
```

and then the Error pops up:

```
unsatisfiableError: The following specificantios were found to be in 
conflict:
- pulp -> python 2.7* 
- python 3.6*
```

whats the problem doesnt pulp work for python 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work with python 3 perhaps just install it with pip

pip install pulp

Make sure you are running the right pip for your anaconda install

Comment: Yes. ```pulp``` is one of these cases where anaconda's binaries are not really needed (and might be outdated), thanks to the really good packaging of yours!